# How to create a report to dynamically generates rows for each new entry in POSTGRESQL and php

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql

I have to run multiple queries and generate a tabled report showing the hours certain users have logged working.

```
<tr>
    <th>USERS</th>
            <th>WORKED FROM</th>
            <th>WORKED TO</th>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
            <th>FOR PROFILE</th>
            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
</tr>
```

The above shown are the headers I will be adressing info under. Now what I would like to do is generate a new row for each new user, listing all their info under each heading and then generating a new row if a new entry is added to the database.
I am using php and POSTGRESQL

Comment: Can you give expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working, took a while tho

```
<?php
    $curr_userno = $logtime->valueof('user_number');
    $tot_mins = 0;
    while (!$logtime->eof()) {
        while (!$timestamp->eof()) {


            if ($curr_userno != $logtime->valueof('user_number')) {
                $total_time = floor($tot_mins / 60) . " hours " . ($tot_mins % 60)." minutes"
                ?>
                <tr>

                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>  
                    <td align="right"><b>Total =</b></td>
                    <td colspan="8"><b><?php echo $total_time; ?></b></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>

                </tr>

                <?php
                $curr_userno = $logtime->valueof('user_number');
                $tot_mins = 0;
            }
            $tot_mins = ($tot_mins + $logtime->valueof('diff') * 60) + $timestamp->valueof('difference');
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    while (!$users->eof()) {
                        if ($users->valueof('userno') == $logtime->valueof('user_number')) {
                            echo $users->valueof('auth_name') . ' ' . $users->valueof('auth_surname');

                            $users->first();
                            break;
                        }
                        $users->next();
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>

                <td><?php echo $logtime->valueof('start_time') ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $logtime->valueof('end_time') ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $logtime->valueof('diff') . " " . "hours" . " " . $timestamp->valueof('difference') . " " . "minutes"; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                    while (!$profiles->eof()) {
                        if ($profiles->valueof('profile_id') == $logtime->valueof('profile_id')) {
                            echo $profiles->valueof('profile_name');
                            $profiles->first();
                            break;
                        }
                        $profiles->next();
                    }
                    ?> 
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $logtime->valueof('description') ?></td>
            </tr>

            <?php
            $timestamp->next();
            $logtime->next();
        }
        echo "<hr></hr>";
    }
    $total_time = floor($tot_mins / 60) . " hours " . ($tot_mins % 60)." minutes";
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td></td>  
        <td align="right"><b>Total =</b></td>
        <td colspan="8"><b><?php echo $total_time; ?></b></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>


    <?php
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="8"><hr></hr></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The code after my initial post I used to get it working

Comment: Yeah, was my first stackoverflow post, but I entered a valid answer now so everything should be fine